# Can't install language packs on office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

I try to install a language pack on Office 2016 , but the installation fail at beginning with this message :

> Couldn't stream office.
>
> Sorry we can't find a required file. Please check that the
>   installation source is reachable , then try again.
>
> Error code : 30812-4 (2)

I have downloaded language pack from Microsoft website :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-2016-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f

I've tried with different language packs and it's the same situation.

I have also reformatted my PC , I've installed again windows 10 and office 2016 , and after I've tried again to install the language packs , but still it's the same error.

What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sorry friend , but I have reformatted my Pc and I have re-installed Windows 10 and office 2016 , - I have no proxy - I have disabled the firewall and windows defender and I have no other antivirus or security software. So none of the causes published on that site is not true for me.

Comment: A cause might be if you use pirated Volume Licensing version and tools to activate it. As it says in the note, the Volume edition has different Language Packs files.

Comment: If someone is willing to install only Proofing tools, just visit `https://www.microsoft.com/<desired-language-code>/download/details.aspx?id=52668` where language code can be en-US for US english, pt-br for Brazilian Portuguese, ca-ES for Spanish Catalan...

Answer (score 2):

Office 2016 Language Accessory Packs need Internet connection to install fully. Please make sure that you have an active Internet connection and it does take some time for the language pack to be installed. Please be patient. And also make sure that you are installing only 32-bit or 64-bit components of Office and not both. Otherwise, you will run into other problems like [listed here](https://superuser.com/questions/993425/language-accessory-pack-for-office-2016-fails-to-install-on-64-bit-office/1060945#1060945).

Answer (score -3):

just copy the language pack insulation file to setup office directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office

and run it