# Language Accessory Pack for Office 2016 fails to install on 64-bit Office

Tags: 64-bit, language, microsoft-office-2016

Although the [official site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-2016-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f) states the following:

**"The language accessory pack files that are available for download in the table below, can be installed on either 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Office 2016."**

When the English language pack is downloaded, I receive the following file *setuplanguagepack.x86.en-us_.exe*, which fails to install on a 64-bit Volume Licensing Office 2016 installation with the following message:

> We're sorry, Office (32-bit) couldn'T be installed because you have these 64-bit Office programes installed on your computer:
>
> Microsoft Office 32-bit Components
>
> 2016 Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016

Is this a bug or I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Are there any errors in the Event Logs? [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: "We're sorry, Office (32-bit) couldn'T be installed because you have these 64-bit Office programes installed on your computer:

Microsoft Office 32-bit Components 2016
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016"

Comment: Are you using a Volume Licensing edition of Microsoft Office 2016 by chance?  *If you are then you are not using the correct file.*  I can't tell what is the error and what is the rest of your question.  So if you already made it clear you are using a VL edition of Office that is the source of my confusion.

Comment: I am, that's what I meant by VL above.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it. Returning to the questions, which is the right language pack for VL then?

Comment: @hoppy - I had already made the edit.  Based on the wording on the website the proper file isn't on that website.  It isn't clear the reason the filename would have x86 contained within it.  In the distribution of Office Microsoft uses x86 and x64 to indicate 32-bit and 64-bit versions of it within the filename.  It is interesting I was able to find evidence that "setuplanguagepack.x64.en-us_.exe" exists.  This tells me the website simply is providing the wrong file, but even if it was the correct file, the message indicates your suppose to use something specific for VL installations.

Comment: See if [this](https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?ProductreleaseID=languagepack&amp;language=en-us&amp;platform=x64&amp;source=O16LAP&amp;version=O16GA) works for you.  You can modify the platform on any pack by switching x86 to x64.  If it works for you I will submit an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot access your link. But [it seems](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/p/414177/1029660#1029660), there are special _Volume Licensing editions of Language Pack and/or Language Interface Pack and/or Proofing Tools_.

Comment: @hoppy - The link I provided started to download for me which means the file does exist.  The answer provided in that thread isn't consistence.  Did you happen to get the "Service Unavailable" error?  You should try switching the url yourself. Copy the link, change x86 to x64, doing so always works for me.  After I use the link once it returns a "service  unavailable" message though

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, thanks, now I got the file. During install, same error window, but now complaining instead of the 64-bit issue to the Click-to-Run incompatibility, similar to the thread I linked.

Comment: @hoppy - Alright.  So your problem is you need the correct installer.  I don't know where you get the VL language packs for Office 2016 though.  Since the installer does not solve your problem I will skip submitting an answer for it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/993425/language-accessory-pack-for-office-2016-fails-to-install-on-64-bit-office#new-answer?newreg=4c4a4f4ecc554d15b3f650058ab0275a

Answer (score 2):

I had gotten into similar problem and got rid of it using the [solution on this Office 2016 language packs download page](https://www.itechtics.com/download-free-office-2016-language-packs-languages/). Here's the solution,

Since you have installed 32-bit and 64-bit components of Office 2016 together, you will need to uninstall either one of them. The safest way is to uninstall Office 2016 completely and install one version. Do not use setup.exe provided in the Microsoft Office 2016 DVD. Instead, open the "Office" folder and run setup32.exe or setup64.exe appropriately.

After the clean installation, you should be able to install the language pack without any problems.

Comment: there is nothing new in what you wrote, we already tried the links you mention, please read the comments above. Also, there are no two versions of Office on my system, the issue is that I have a VL edition.

Comment: hoppy I also have two versions of Office installed on my system: Office 2013 Pro Plus and Office 2016 Pro Plus. Both are 64-bit but when I first installed Office 2016 with one click install, I encountered the same error as you specified. I uninstalled Office 2016 completely and installed it using the setup64.exe file in the Office folder.